# How to generate select query for a table based on the value of another table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have two tables A and B.

Table A has structure like below:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | ....
```

Table B has only one entry with many columns, for example ( just taking 5) :

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 ...
-- -- -- -- --
 1  0  1  1  0 ...
```

Now I want to generate query dynamically in a stored procedure based the value of table B row. Only select columns which has corresponding value 1.

**Example 1:** For above entry query will look like :

```
select col1,
       col3,
       col4
from A;
```

**Example 2 :** If entry in B is like below

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 ...
-- -- -- -- --
 0  0  1  1  0 ...
```

For above entry query will look like :

```
select col3,
       col4
from A;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good table design to store columns as lookup values. You may achieve it using `UNPIVOT`, but the mapping has to be explicitly listed.

```
SELECT 
     'SELECT ' ||LISTAGG(
          CASE
               WHEN col = 1 THEN val
          END,',') WITHIN GROUP(
          ORDER BY col
     ) ||' FROM A' as query
  FROM b UNPIVOT ( col
       FOR val
  IN ( c1 as 'COL1',
       c2 as 'COL2',
       c3 as 'COL3',
       c4 as 'COL4',
       c5 as 'COL5') );
```

[**demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1bdfeb40e021891c3f59925138aa3482)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  Can u also suggest some good table desing for same type of requirement ?

Comment: @Laxmikant : It's hard to tell what suits your original requirement since you have already arrived at a point where you want to use this as a solution. Having said that, generally in rdbms it's always wise and efficient to store values as rows of a table rather than as columns(c1,c2,c3...etc) and avoid dynamic sql statements as far as possible.